# Using lambda functions in python like MATLAB anonymous function

Tags: python, matlab, lambda, anonymous-function

This is a valid use of an anonumous function in MATLAB, where I define FootToHead() function in another file

```
f2h = @(x,xdata)FootToHeadY(x,xdata,rawPoints(1,6)/100.);
```

Is it possible to make the same thing using lambda functions in Python?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can easily do this with a `lambda`

```
f2h = lambda x, xdata: FootToHeadY(x, xdata, rawPoints(1,6) / 100.);
```

In a `lambda` function, the input arguments are in a comma-separated list between the `lambda` and the `:`. The contents of the `lambda` function are identical to the contents of your anonymous function.

To actually *invoke* this function, you'd need to call `f2h` with your desired inputs (just like you would in MATLAB)

```
f2h(1, 2)
```

Comment: Doing so the interpreter doesn't even enter in the function FootToHeadY().

Comment: @fsart: Of course it doesn't. It wouldn't enter `FootToHeadY` in your Matlab code either. You didn't call `f2h`.